# Componentization of web project

Tags: deployment, web-applications, spring-mvc, automated-deploy

I have been working on spring-mvc for last 3 months and its been lot productive compared to my earlier work.
I kept adding lot of featuers in the web application and now am stuck with the simple problem.

All the features I have added wont be used in all deployments and I need to figure out a way to exclude some features at the time of deployment. Some other deployment need different set of exclusions.

Exclusion means I want to get rid of jsps/controllers/dao/service code while deploying the application. 
Package structure as well as directory structure for jsps is good enough that I can separate out the part I don't want for particular deployment.

Right now I can do it manually and with some added parameters I can have ant task to do that stuff too.
I want to hear about the better approaches for this problem. Considering am done with only 50% of total development I want to get rid of this problem as soon as possible. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Separate jars for the elements to be used independently? Last time I did this, the only problem I ran into was that jsps could not be used that way (easily), so I had a custom ant/maven task/goal to ensure the jsps were taken from the jars and placed in the war. So I was not excluding parts, but selecting the elements to include (I assume that is OK for you too).

But now, with OSGi, I believe you can have truly modular web applications. An [intro into modular web applications with Spring and OSGi](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/04/29/web-applications-and-osgi/) might be of interest, although it refers to the unreleased version a proper [released version](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.0/reference/html-single/#dm-1.1.x:web:spring-mvc) is available.

Comment: I found another good entry on the Modularizing existing web applications using OSGi. Would be useful to read this one too

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?track=NL-461&ad=741661&l=MigratingPathToOSGi&asrc=EM_NLN_10448279&uid=3109212